# iframe versus div + jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, html

I would like to know what is the more appropriate for what I want to achieve:

On my main page (main.php), I have links to different forms: form1.php, form2.php, form3.php. I need the pages of the links to open in a portion of main.php, i.e in a div or in a iframe on main.php, without refreshing main.php. The form pages enables to populate, delete, update a database. When I do those actions, I don't want main.php to refresh but only the appropriate form page.
My first option is to open form1.php for example in a iframe of main.php. When I submit a form, only form1.php in the iframe is refreshed.
My second option is to use jquery: open the link (form1.php) in a div of main.php.
Submit the form within the div, and refresh the div only.

The second option is more demanding since I do not have much experience with ajax and jquery. The first option is more straight forward for me.
I am wondering if there is any advantages to use the second option with a div refresh compared to iframe, i.e compatibility with different browsers and else...
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using jquery, ajax(XMLHttpRequest). Iframes are old, not semantic and you cannot access to an iframe within main.php.

```
$("#submit_button_id").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('form.php', $("#form_name").serialize(), function(result) { 
        $("#div_id").html(result); } }
```

this snippet should work.
`$("#submit_button_id").click(function(e) {` : catches the click function of the assigned id and creates a trigger.

`e.preventDefault();` : prevents the form submit regularly, we are going to submit it by jquery.

`$.post` sends the form in `POST` method.

`'form.php'` is your form controller which is going to return an html code to be shown.

`("#form_name").serialize()` this function is a utility for serializing form to be sent. it loads the input fields and converts them to like `{ field1: value, field2: value }`

`function(result) {` is the 3rd parameter, on success, `$.post` calls the 3rd parameter as a function. we create an anonymous function to replace html of our div.

`$("#div_id").html(result)` sets the assigned div's html to `result` variable.

refer to http://api.jquery.com/ , they have a wonderful reference sheet.

Comment: I have been trying your code, and have few questions:
Is there a way to check that the values of the form were posted. Usually, with regular form submission, I would check if the items were posted by displaying the values: <?php echo("email: $email"); ?> for instance. How can I do that here.
Also, I don't understand what "result" is? Could you give me an example? 
One of the thing I would like to do is after the form is submitted, the page form1.php woudl refresh to show the field value in a non-editable form, like: email= example@gmail.com, country: USA, etc...

Comment: There are many ways to check it, if you want to check it server-side, you can use `$_POST['email']` variable with some regex functions. or if you want to check if they are not `null` use `if($_POST['email'])`  if you want to do that on client-side it will be faster as it is checking the fields before submitting, however, this can be bypassed easily  so always implement server-side check.

Comment: The "result" is simply html code generated from the form1.php script.  e.g. `if($_POST['name']) echo 'form submitted'`. this snippet will generate a text "form submitted", and it is the `result` variable which will dynamically refreshed via XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Summed all, you need to make a form validation as showed above, and `echo` the results you want to look like. Bear in mind, avoid echoing html tags within php file unless it is necessary, just include them in your main html file. it does not do any harm, but it is generally a bad practise

Comment: Thanks for your time. I don't know what's wrong, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: This is the code for main.php:
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/update-div.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#fc').delegate(".submit", "click", function(eventform) {
 eventform.preventDefault();
        $('#fc').load('form1.php', { 'name': $('input[name="name"]').val()}); 
 });
 });
</script>           
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('form1.php','fc')">form1</a>
<br><br><br>
<div id="fc"></div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: this is the code of form1.php:
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$birth = $_POST['birth'];
$act = $_POST['act'];
$query="INSERT INTO `dbase` (`name`,`birth`) VALUES ('$name','$birth')";
mysql_query($query);
$id=mysql_insert_id();
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php
if(!empty($name)){
    $html = "Name:".$name;
    $html .= "Birth:".$birth;   
    echo("$html");
}
else{ ?>
<form name="form1">
Name <input type='text' name='name'>
<br/>
Birthplace : <input type="text" name="birth"><br/>
<input type='submit' name='act' value='save' id="submit_btn"/>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>

Comment: As u'll see I replaced:
$.post('form1.php', $("#form1").serialize(), function(result) { 
        $("#fc").html(result); } }
by: $('#fc').load('form1.php', { 'name': $('input[name="name"]').val()});
but I am not happy with it because I have to write down the name of all inputs. I'd prefer to use "serialize".
Here is what does not work: main.php refreshes on clicking "submit" and shows the url: main.php?name=ERRRR&birth=&act=save
The second issue is that when populating the dbase, $name is empty.

Comment: It is pain to read the code like that, please submit a new question that you can put your code that be read

Comment: @JMarc let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2179/discussion-between-fastreload-and-jmarc)

Comment: I opened a new thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966891/run-a-form-insert-update-delete-from-within-a-div-using-jquery, related to this one.

Comment: Wow, I got it working now. The reason that the entries were not posted is because I did not give a id name to the form.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$("#div").load("form.php");` from jQuery

> This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success) except that it is a method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback function. When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data.

Reference: [.load() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: @Umur Kontacı can you explain why you said this above? "you cannot access to an iframe within main.php"

Comment: What an ingenious method!