# Run a form (insert/update/delete) from within a div using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, html

This is a followup of a previous question: "iframe versus div + jquery". I load a form (form1.php) in a div of main.php. I want to be able to run the form within the div without refreshing main.php to populate a db.
Here is main.php:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/update-div.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_btn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('form1.php', $("#form1").serialize(), function(result) { 
            $("#fc").html(result); });
        });
    </scrip>
    </head>
    <body leftmargin="0px" topmargin="0px" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <a href="javascript:ajaxpage('form1.php','fc')">form1</a>
    <br>
    <div id="fc"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and this is the code for form1.php

```
    <?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'login', 'pwd');
    if (!$link) {die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());}
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db('db_name');
    $name = strtoupper($_POST['name']);
    $birth = strtoupper($_POST['birth']);
    $act = $_POST['act'];
    if($act == "save"){
    $query="INSERT INTO `mnl_people` ( `name` , `birth`) VALUES ('$name', '$birth')";
    mysql_query($query);
    $idalbum=mysql_insert_id();
    }
    if(!empty($name)){
    $html = "<p>Your name: <b>".$name."</b></p>";
    $html .= "<p>Your birthplace: <b>".$birth."</b></p>";   
    echo("$html");
    }
    else{ ?>
    <form name="form1" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    Name <input type='text' name='name' value=""><br>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Birthplace : <input type="text" name="birth"><br/>

    <input type='submit' name='act' class='submit' value='save' id="submit_btn"/>
    </form>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Unfortunately, on submit click, main.php refreshes and show the following url: mnl/main.php?name=Johnb&birth=us&act=save. Also, eventhough a new field is added to the table 'mnl_people', there is no values for the field `name` and `birth`: i.e it seems that $name and $birth are empty. Could someone le me know what I am doing wrong. I am definitely missing something here. Thanks.

Comment: The closing script tag has a typo should be `</script>` instead of `</scrip>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [.live](http://Ali.query.com/live) version, so instead of

```
 $("#submit_btn").click(function(e) {
```

Use

```
 $("#submit_btn").live('click',function(e) {
```

The problem is that the moment you are attaching the click handler the form does not exist in the DOM, since you load it with ajax.

Comment: Thanks. Part of it work, now main.php does not refresh, and only the div is refreshed. However, the parameters $name and $birth are still empty.
One more thing, I was reading on a website that delegate() is preferable to live(). I don't remember the exact reason, and the explanation were pretty advanced (I am a jquery beginner). Any thought on that??

Answer (score 1):

You did not declare the method of your form as `POST` so it uses the `GET` method, but you try to get the `POST` values.

Either add an attribute `method="POST"` to your form tag or use `$_GET['field_name']` to retrieve it.